# Substances - A Macroscopic Concept

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Does the term “substance” refer to any sample of matter that is tangible? In other words is “substance” a macroscopic concept or can we also refer to individual particles such as atoms, molecules, etc. as substances?

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on the context**

"Substance" is not a tightly defined term so the argument is largely linguistic not about chemistry. Unless, that is, you are talking about observable chemical properties and use the word. Then, the context of use matters and you might need to be careful in how the word is used.

With gases it doesn't much matter how much stuff you have as the individual molecules don't interact much. But for solids and liquids when you talk about "substance" the apparent chemical properties may depend on how many molecules or atoms you have. So you might need to be careful how many of the components are present. The reason why I say this is that some collections of small numbers of components have different *properties* to larger collections.

Nanoparticles of gold, for example, have different properties to bulk metallic gold. Some show much stronger colours that metallic gold (eg small colloidal gold clusters are used to [impart a red colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_glass) to some specialty glass products). So the small clusters have different properties to bulk gold and you don't see the bulk properties until the amount of gold is large enough.

So although the *substance* of both bulk gold and colloidal clusters of gold atoms might be said to be the same, it is probably better to be more specific and talk about colloidal clusters as being a different "substance" to bulk gold. But this isn't universally agreed as usage of *substance* is not precisely defined.

In short, if you are talking purely about what something is made from then the amount doesn't matter and you can say substance for any amount but if you are talkingg about the *properties* of the material it can be better to be specific as the properties do change with the amount of the components involved.

Comment: So if I were to say that “sodium” is a reactive substance would I be referring to sodium atoms or sodium metal?

Comment: @Interestinggg For sodium it would make no difference. Pure metals contain atoms not molecules of their element so, in reactions, act like they react one atom at a time in simple reactions.

Comment: Alright so elements are substances “made up of one type of atom”. And sodium is an element. So why can we say that sodium “has one valence electron” when sodium is a substance not a type of atom?

Comment: @Interestinggg Context. And note that just because sodium is a substance doesn't mean we can't talk about sodium atoms. Sodium is both a type of atom *and* a substance. If we talk valence electrons the context tests us we are talking about atoms; if we talk "soft, reactive metal" we are talking about the bulk substance.

Comment: Could you just explain what the “made up of one type of atom” thing means. This would clear a lot of confusion. Regards.

Comment: @Interestinggg It isn't complicated. A lump of pure sodium metal only contains sodium atoms and no other type of atom. An oxygen molecule only contains oxygen atoms; oxygen gas contains oxygen molecules which consist only of two oxygen atoms.

Comment: An element is more like a form of matter isn’t it? As opposed to a physical aggregation of particles?

Comment: @Interestinggg "element" is a much broader term than that. Single atoms are by definition elements. small aggregates of atoms can be mede up from a single element. Large aggregates can be mad from a single element but don't have to be. Many of the properties of an element in large aggregates are often called the properties of the element but some elements form more than one type of aggregate. Ozone and dioxygen are both molecular forms of oxygen; diamond and graphite are both aggregates of carbon.